# php session.save_path has no value

Tags: php, session

Hi,

No sessions are being created on my server so I checked with phpinfo and I realized session.save_path has no value.

Is this by any chance preventing PHP from creating sessions like this?

```
session_start();
// if we haven't set redirect, assume we want to redirect
if (!isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to set `session.save_path` specifically (no set value is default).  Left as default I believe it user `/tmp`.

It is wise though to change it if your server has shared access.

Have a look a the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) for more info on this.

As for no sessions being created.  Change the path to something specific and look there.

Its worth noting as well that if you're using a load balancer, using file based sessions can mean that the server handling requests at that time might not have access to the sessions set by the other servers, so its best to use a common point, such as a Redis server (or many other solutions) to solve this.